# Stored procedure with inner join using coalesce

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have a simple table tblAllUsers which stores simple values like Name,Date Of Birth etc of a UserId.

Another table tblInterest stores the interest(s) of a UserId.Here a user may have any number of Interest and are stored seperately in separate rows :

```
 Create table tblInterest
 (
 Id int primary key identity,
 UserId varchar(10),
 InterestId int,
 Interest varchar(20)
 )
```

So when i want to display the set of Interest together of a particular user, I use the below query :

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)   
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ', ' ,'') + Interest FROM tblInterest where UserId=@UserId   
SELECT @listStr
```

Now, want to display a users info from both these tables wherein the Interest(S) are displayed in ONE string.

I have tried the below ;

```
 Create proc spPlayersGridview
 @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
 as
 begin
 Select  tblAllUsers.Category, tblAllUsers.DOB, tblAllUsers.FirstName, tblAllUsers.LastName, tblAllUsers.City, tblAllUsers.State,
 @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ', ' ,'') + tblInterest.Interest
 from tblAllUsers
 INNER JOIN tblInterest
 ON tblAllUsers.UserId=tblInterest.UserId
 where Category='Player'
 end
```

throws an exception "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations."

Comment: remove your this part `tblAllUsers.Category, tblAllUsers.DOB, tblAllUsers.FirstName, tblAllUsers.LastName, tblAllUsers.City, tblAllUsers.State,` from the SELECT query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back, and a bit of SQL STUFF magic helps - Maybe it will work for you as well.

```
CREATE PROC spPlayersGridview
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
      tblAllUsers.Category
    , tblAllUsers.DOB
    , tblAllUsers.FirstName
    , tblAllUsers.LastName
    , tblAllUsers.City
    , tblAllUsers.State
    , listStr  = STUFF((
                    SELECT ',' + tblInterest.Interest
                    FROM tblInterest
                    WHERE tblAllUsers.UserId=tblInterest.UserId
                    ORDER BY tblInterest.Interest
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    FROM tblAllUsers
    WHERE Category='Player'
END
```

Hope it helps - For more reading look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Comment: You should also note that he is trying to return a stored procedure with one value in it at the moment, he'll either need to change the return type or use a table-valued function

Comment: @Wibbler Yeah you are right, but his goal is to "display a users info from both these tables wherein the Interest(S) are displayed in ONE string" And that can be done this way, without any indput variable or table-valued function.